# How to select a word in a string only if it is longer then two characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string, filter

given a string like "city of region" I can get single words I need by index of array, but how to skip short words such "of" and get region?

```
let fullName = model.institution?.nome ?? "N/A"
let firstWord = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ").first ?? "N/A"
var seconWord = ""       
if fullName.components(separatedBy: " ").count > 1 {
    seconWord = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")[1]
}      
self.institutionNameLabel.text = fullName
if let idEnte = model.institution?.idEnte {
    self.subtitleLable.text = "\(idEnte)"
}
let a = firstWord.first ?? "N"
let b = seconWord.first ?? "N"
self.initialsRoundLabel.text = "\(a)\(b)"
```

Comment: right! so simple and clean! thanks! if you want to add the answer I can sign as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only get words longer than 2 from `fullName` you can do

```
let words = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0.count > 2}
```